Android 12: Unable to use the launcher's built-in call over bluetooth function. How to change the default?
In my car I have a device running Android 12 and I tend to have my phone connected via Bluetooth. When I want to make a call or receive a call while driving it should use the built-in calling interface in the launcher that I'm using (AutoZen). However, I'm always greeted with an unbearably ugly interface and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.
This is the interface that I want to use.
This is the interface that automatically pops up and it becomes the only way for me to interact with my phone over Bluetooth. How do I prevent this awful interface from appearing again? I just want to keep using the interface that came with the launcher.
I've tried looking in the list of apps to see if I can disable anything related to Bluetooth calling and music links so I can switch the link to opening with AutoZen. Unfortunately I haven't found anything that works. I'm also considering to root the device but I have no experience with that.
